# How to get the actual instace of the navigated Page after a Frame.Navigate call?

Tags: .net, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In UWP, the Frame.Navigate methods use a `sourcePageType` (`Type`) as parameters to know the kind of page to navigate to.

I would like to know if there's a way to obtain the actual instance of the navigated `Page` (created as a part of the navigation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the navigation is done, you can get the page instance from the `Frame`'s `Content`.

Soonest you can get it is probably after the `Frame.Navigated` event which you can subscribe to.